# How to install Jad?

Tags: installation, java

I'm very new to Ubuntu. I need a way to install [Jad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29) in my system.

Can anyone help me this out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JAD Java Decompiler is a handy tool for Java developers, both for academic use and for recovering your own code on those (hopefully) rare occasions when you lose the source but have the .class files.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Javamate](http://javamate.net/2007/11/18/how-to-get-jad-java-decompiler-working-in-ubuntu/)</sup>

To install it, you can download it [Here](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/). I recommend that you get the static binary.

It's a 32-bit binary, so you may also want to add the install ia32-libs if you get any problems...

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Also move/copy it to something in the path, like /usr/local/bin, so you can run jad

<sup>(Thanks to izx for his kindness)</sup>

Comment: I'm getting error like this : `E: Unable to locate package libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2'`

Comment: Thanks, I tried installing using `dpkg`. But I get : `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2:i386:
 libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.2.4-4).
dpkg: error processing libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2:i386`

Comment: I just installed, using GDebi, and it installed fine.  To get GDebi [click here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gdebi/)

Comment: Thanks. I have installed using Gdebi. But when I tried to open `jad` using command line. I get command not found error.

Comment: you probably need to add it to your path then.. that'll fix your command not found error..