# How to Install and Use JAD

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I am attempting to install [JAD](http://varaneckas.com/jad/) on Ubuntu 14.10.

I have downloaded the Jad 1.5.8e for Linux on Intel platform download. And I have unzipped the jad158e.linux.intel.zip file and am reading the Readme.txt file which says for installation:

```
1. Installation.

Unzip jad.zip file into any appropriate directory on your hard drive.
This will create two files:

- an executable file named 'jad.exe' (Windows *)
  or 'jad' (*n*x)

- this README file

No other setup is required.
```

And then to use it it says to:

```
2. How to use Jad

To decompile a single JAVA class file 'example1.class' 
type the following:

 jad example1.class
```

And I have tried executing the jad file that comes in the zip by locating it in Terminal using the cd command and then executing it with this command:

```
./jad
```

But that only gets me this result:

```
./jad: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried just locating the file that I want to decompile like it says in the instructions by locating it with `cd` and then doing:

```
jad MyJavaApplication.class
```

But all that returns is this error:

```
No command 'jad' found, but there are 17 similar ones
jad: command not found
```

I had a good look at several forums such as [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=919353) and this askubuntu question [How to install Jad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169885/how-to-install-jad). But I still haven't been able to get JAD working. I even tried installing Gdebi as suggested in one of the forums that I mentioned above. But no matter what I do I cannot seem to get it to work. So really what my question is is, how do I install and use JAD? 
I heard something about adding it to the PATH variable and that I need to move it to this directory /usr/local/bin, but when moving it to that directory it tells me that I need more privileges even though I am that admin. And I am unsure of how to add it to the PATH variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"Workaround" for the `libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3` Problem**

It seems the last update for JAD was from 2001 and was compiled for Linux 2.0.0. The dependency `libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3` that JAD references probably doesn't exist anymore... (Well it probably does exist somewhere but it would be a mess to install and use it!)

The good news is that below the "Jad 1.5.8e for Linux on Intel platform" download there is a statically linked version of the software available ("Jad 1.5.8e for Linux (statically linked)") that includes all required dependencies *and does not require anything to be installed on your system*. It will therefor work on any i386 compatible Linux system! I tried in on my 64-bit Linux system and it just works.

**The `jad: command not found` problem**

The problem with running `jad MyJavaApplication.class` is that it requires JAD to be in your application search path. So you can:

1. `cd` to the JAD directory, type `export PATH="${PWD}:${PATH}"`, then `cd` to the directory with your `*.class* file(s) and run`jad MyJavaApplication.class`
2. Create a directory called `bin` in your home directory and copy the `jad` binary there. Then open a new terminal, `cd` to the directory with your `*.class*` file(s) and run `jad MyJavaApplication.class`. (You will only have to copy the `jad` file once!)

   3. Move the `jad` file to your `/bin` directory with: `sudo cp /path/to/jad/executable/file /bin`.

Note: JAD is from 2001 and has been developed for Java 1.5/Java 5 currently we use Java 7 and Java 8 is just around the corner, expect problems when decompiling modern Java files!

Don't forget to upvote, mark as accepted answer if this worked for you!

Comment: Great answer by the way! It really helped me out when I first started using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

For first problem, you can download `static jad` form this [link](https://varaneckas.com/jad/jad158e.linux.static.zip), so it needs nothing. For second problem, you can simply do `./jad file.class`.